# Obtener el primer registro y sumar fila cuando empieza una condición SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Un saludo a toda la comunidad.

Tengo la duda de cómo obtener un campo (`emision`) primer registro de una tabla cuando empieza una condición y la suma a partir de esta condición:

Mi tabla es la siguiente:

[image: Tabla]

Deseo obtener solo la emisión de cuando el `saldo_a_restar` empieza a ser positivo y la suma de los valores del campo `IoE` a partir de ahí, en todo caso me quedaría algo como esto:

| indiceCliente | Cliente | Emision | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK | 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | 945.4 |

He intentado lo siguiente:

```sql
SET @emisionActual = (SELECT TOP(1) emision FROM tabla1 WHERE cliente = @clienteActual)
SET @totalActual = (SELECT SUM(IoE) FROM tabla1 WHERE indiceCliente = @count)
```

Pero me bota el error de:
`La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el orden que dices se mantiene, no bastaría con hacer una agregación?:

```
SELECT
    IndiceCliente,
    Cliente,
    MIN(Emision) Emision,
    SUM(IoE) Total
FROM dbo.Tabla
WHERE saldo_a_restar >= 0
GROUP BY
    IndiceCliente,
    Cliente
;
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes realizar lo siguiente.

```
select IndiceCliente, Cliente,MIN(emision) Emision,SUM(Ioe) Total from @tb where Saldo_a_restar>0 group by IndiceCliente, Cliente
```

Comment: ¿qué hace tu query?  porque lo que estás sugiriendo, resuelve su problema?